# Trying to understand LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that will take data from a DB and I would like to return a single object back.

However the following code will return null back.

I already verified that the dt coming in contains 1 record.

This method works if I change the return type from an object to a list of objects.

I am tying to understand why in this case and why I can't return just a single object.

```
    public PersonObj GetPersonInformation(string personName)
    {
        DataTable dt = _oracle.GetPersonInformation(personName);
        var aPerson = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => 
                    new PersonObj
                    {
                        FirstName = x.Field<string>("FIRST_NAME"),
                        LastName = x.Field<string>("LAST_NAME"),
                        PhoneNumber = x.Field<string>("PHONE_NUMBER")
                    }).ToList().Take(1);

        return aPerson as PersonObj;
    }
```

Comment: From linked duplicate: "Finally, the difference between First() and Take() is that First() returns the element itself, while Take() returns a sequence of elements that contains exactly one element. (If you pass 1 as the parameter)."

Comment: Side note: it is expected that author of the question performs some basic investigation (i.e. reads MSDN articles on each method used in the question for C#), not doing so (or not demonstrating results) does not reflect well on author and also may trigger a lot of downvotes on the post itself (even if post did nothing wrong - they can't fix themselves)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [`Take(1)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx), do [`First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx)

`Take(n)` returns an `IEnumerable` of Count `n` (in your case, an `IEnumerable` of Count 1) whereas `First()` returns the first object in the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: That worked, but why can't I use Take(1)?

Comment: because Take(1) does not return one object, it returns a list containing one object.  (btw, I mean list in the generic sense, not List<T>)

Comment: @JDS See my edit.  `Take()` is a general method that will return an `IEnumerable` of however long you give it.  For this reason, it's consistent to return an `IEnumerable` of count 1 instead of the first element.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because `Take` returns an IEnumerable. This is because you can specify the amount to take. What would happen, for example, if you did this?

```
    public PersonObj GetPersonInformation(string personName, int take)
        {
            DataTable dt = _oracle.GetPersonInformation(personName);
            return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => 
                        new PersonObj
                        {
                            FirstName = x.Field<string>("FIRST_NAME"),
                            LastName = x.Field<string>("LAST_NAME"),
                            PhoneNumber = x.Field<string>("PHONE_NUMBER")
                        }).ToList().Take(take);

        }
```

You might ask for (and get) one, but you might ask for more. This shows why you're getting the error: `Take(1)` returns an IEnumerable with 1 element, not a single element itself.

If you just want the first one, you can call `First()` instead.

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault(), not First(), to avoid possible exceptions

Comment: @Joe that's your opinion... No reason not to use `First` if you know for sure there is an element to return, or if you'd rather an exception get thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using FirstOrDefault() instead of Take(1)?  That should allow you to specify that you expect only a single result.
I believe the reason you are having a problem with the datatype is due to the ToList() and Take() call, which can return more than one object.